# Reasons for the recommendations about Cassandra seed nodes configuration?

Tags: cassandra

I understand the seed nodes play the role of a "first point of contact" in the gossip protocol which allows the nodes to discover and maintain the list of their peers.

The documentation recommends the following.

- A) Start the seeds one at a time, then the remaining nodes in the cluster.
- B) Define the same seeds on each node.

I am not sure why. Below is my best guess.

- A) If all the nodes started at the same time, one of them might contact a seed which does not have the right information yet. This might prevent/delay the lists of peers convergence.
- B) This is because the seeds have more up-to-date information than the other nodes. As such the lists of peers converge faster if all the nodes use the same seeds.

Are my guesses correct? Is there any other reason? Are there cases where the lists of peers cannot converge because the seeds are configured differently on each node, or the nodes are not started in the right order?

Answer (score 2):

It's important to point out that seed nodes are only relevant when a node first joins the cluster, e.g. when adding a new node to manage capacity. The node will contact the seed node as the first point of contact to get the current node list and topology. After that, the list is maintained through gossip, even when a node goes down and comes back online, so once a node has joined the cluster, seeds are no longer relevant.

To me, those recommendations are to ensure a clean startup of a new cluster.

A) For obvious reasons, the seeds should be started before non-seed nodes. Starting seed nodes one at a time ensure that nodes which start after the first will be able to contact an existing node you start up and get the cluster info. Otherwise they may think they are the first node in the cluster and spend time doing initial setup -- the nodes *should* eventually converge to form the desired cluster, but it may take longer.

B) If you have different seeds on each node, then you may inadvertently setup a node startup order which has to be followed for successful cluster creation. e.g. if C and D has seeds A and B, but E has seeds C,D, then you will need to set your configuration to start C or D after A or B, and then start E after that, even though they may all be seed nodes. 
This rule lets you set your configuration to: Start seeds (any order) then start non-seeds (any order).